# Learn python the hard way ex25

Tags: python

[image: code I am running]
[image: functions called upon]

why does the first use of "sorted_words" return the sorted_words WITHOUT the words "All" and "wait
why does the second use of "sorted_words" return the sorted_words WITHOUT the words "All" and "who"
BUT if we look below
When I use "sorted_words" one more time at the bottom,
all the words are there. What is different when I call on this again this time
that is different from the previous two times where the words were not shown, but
now they are shown here?

Comment: Please read [why you should not upload images of code when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Please review the guidelines for creating a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can adjust/format your question appropriately.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The methods you're using on 'sorted_words' are 'popping' the first/last words of the list. That means they are removing them from the list, so they won't appear again.

When they reappear later, it's because you're acting on your original sentence string, not the sorted_words list.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me. Much appreciated.